# C++ inheritance, and hiding unwanted inherited functions

Tags: c++, inheritance

I am trying to implement a [QToolBar](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/stable/qtoolbar.html) subclass, which has its items specified by a model, instead of added individually. This means a selection of functions to add/remove items (toolbar buttons), such as addAction shouldn't be publicly accessible.

What is the best way to inherit from this object, but make a selection of functions private?

My current best idea is to do like this:

```
class ToolbarView : public QToolBar
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit ToolbarView(QWidget *parent = 0);

signals:

public slots:

private:

    void addAction (QAction *action) {Q_UNUSED(action)};
    QAction* addAction (const QString &text) {return QToolBar::addAction(text) ;}
    ...
    QAction* addSeparator() {QToolBar::addSeparator();}
    ... [list of about 10 of these]

};
```

So, redefining all the functions that should not be public, as private.

Is this a good idea, or are there better methods?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As long as you inherit publicly from `QToolBar`, you make it possible for a client code to treat your object as such and call for example the `addAction` member function. If you want to ensure that these functions are inaccessible, you'll have do this the other way :

- Inherit privately from `QToolBar`
- Publicly expose the functions you wish to expose (for example with `using` declarations)

If you want to stick with your initial solutions and inherit publicly from `QToolbar` :

- Be aware that it doesn't guarantee base class functions won't be called
- You should consider using `using` declarations to change the accessibility of the base class functions instead of hiding them

Comment: +1: for being the only answer that is complete. `private` inheritance *and* `using` declarations to expose the non-private functions.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you could think of this

```
class ToolbarView : private QToolBar
{
    //...
}
```

In such case, all of accessible QToolBar will be with private access in your ToolbarView .

Answer (score 1):

You are publically inheriting from `QToolbar`. How about changing that to `private` inheritance. That, is the class definition should begin as

```
    class ToolbarView : private QToolBar 
    {
    // good only if you want to 
    // make "most" of the public members of QToolBar private in ToolbarView
    }
```